# How did I get this NullReferenceException error here right after the constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception

I've had an asp.net website running live on our intranet for a couple of weeks now. I just got an email from my application_error emailer method with an unhandled exception.

Here it is (I've cleaned up some of the paths to make it better displayed)

> Exception : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Stack Trace : at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
>    at TimesheetDomain.DataMappers.StaffMemberData.ReadStaff(SqlDataReader reader) in TimesheetDomain\DataMappers\StaffMemberData.cs:line 362
>
> at
>   TimesheetDomain.DataMappers.StaffMemberData.GetStaffMember(String
>   name) in
>   TimesheetDomain\DataMappers\StaffMemberData.cs:line
>   401
>
> at
>   TimesheetDomain.ServiceLayer.TimesheetManager.GetUserFromName(String
>   name) in
>   TimesheetDomain\ServiceLayer\TimesheetManager.cs:line
>   199
>
> at UserVerification.GetCurrentUser()
>   in \App_Code\UserVerification.cs:line
>   29 at WebTimesheets.OnInit(EventArgs
>   e) in
>   \WebTimesheets\WebTimesheets.master.cs:line
>   159
>
> at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control
>   namingContainer) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control
>   namingContainer) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Basically it looks like it's erroring at my ReadStaff method which reads a data reader to build staff member objects. Here is the bit of code:

```
while (reader != null && reader.Read())
{
    StaffMember newMember = null;
    string firstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
    string lastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
    int staffID = (int)reader["StaffID"];
    int employSection = (int)reader["EmploySection"];
    StaffType employType = (StaffType)employSection;
    string emailAddress = reader["EmailInt"].ToString();
    int employCode = (int)reader["ibbwid"];

    //check if they are an admin staff member 
    if (IsAdminStaff(employType))
    {
        newMember = new AdminOfficer(firstName, lastName, employType, staffID, emailAddress, employCode);
    }
    else
    {
        //check if they are a supervisor
        if (IsASupervisor(staffID))
            newMember = new Supervisor(firstName, lastName, employType, staffID, emailAddress, employCode);
        else
            newMember = new StaffMember(firstName, lastName, employType, staffID, emailAddress, employCode);
    }

    //add to identity map
    if (!_staffMembers.ContainsKey(staffID))
        _staffMembers.Add(staffID, newMember); //****THIS IS LINE 362*****
    else
        _staffMembers[staffID] = newMember;
}
```

(Line 362 is 3rd last line)
I'm using an identity map (just read fowlers book on patterns and thought it was a good idea - may have done it wrong, happy for comments) but that's not overly relevant as later on I use the `newMember` object elsewhere so if I remove that block the `NullReferenceException` will occur.

I am struggling to see how on earth `newMember` is null in the 3rd last line there (which is the line that errored).

Resharper/VS doesn't give me a warning that it could be `null` - because there's the 3 constructors which I choose from.

Can anyone suggest where I can look to try and fix this error? It's only happened once and that method has been called thousands of times since the site went live.

Thanks

[EDIT]
As Requested, here's the IComparer for staff member

```
/// <summary>
/// Comparer for staff members - compares on name
/// </summary>
public class StaffMemberComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        //check they are staff members
        if (x is StaffMember && y is StaffMember)
        {
            //do a simple string comparison on names
            StaffMember staffX = x as StaffMember;
            StaffMember staffY = y as StaffMember;

            return String.Compare(staffX.FirstName, staffY.FirstName);
        }

        throw new Exception("This is for comparing Staff Members");
    }
}
```

and it's used in the IComparable implementation

```
/// <summary>
/// IComparable implementaiton
/// </summary>
/// <param name="obj">object to compare to</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    StaffMemberComparer comparer = new StaffMemberComparer();
    return comparer.Compare(this, obj);
}
```

Comment: Which line is TimesheetDomain\DataMappers\StaffMemberData.cs:line 362?

Comment: This is irrelevant to the actual question but you can replace the whole `if (!_staffMembers.ContainsKey(staffID)) _staffMembers.Add(staffID, newMember); else _staffMembers[staffID] = newMember;` with just `_staffMembers[staffID] = newMember;`. It would add the key if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: sorry (didn't make it very clear) the 362 line is the 3rd last line in my code block, its _staffMembers.Add(staffID, newMember);

thanks mehrdad, i'll remember that, I thought I did it for a reason but can't remember it now so I'll give your version a go

Answer (score 142, accepted):

It is almost certainly a threading issue - see [this question and its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320621/throw-a-nullreferenceexception-while-calling-the-setitem-method-of-a-dictionary).

`Dictionary<>.Insert()` will throw a `NullReferenceException` internally if the dictionary instance is modified from another thread during the insert operation.

Comment: This is entirely non-obvious, especially if you only see an IDictionary from the outside...

Answer (score 22):

As of .NET 4.0 you can use ConcurrentDictionary and avoid the threading issues associated with manipulating the same dictionary from multiple threads simultaneously.

Comment: Don't say this too loud as ConcurrentDictionary has also it pitfalls, for example if you create resource objects it's possible to create duplicated ones and have memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything obvious. I'd run some SQL to check the database for any bad data. The problem may be a freak bug in a related input form. If the code has been run thousands of times without incident until now, i'd wrap some additional exception handling/reporting around the code block in question so you can at least get a staffId if/when it next happens.

You could burn a lot of time on something like this. The most expedient approach may be just to let it fail again under the above/controlled conditions..... assuming the level of disruption it causes is acceptable/manageable/minor.

I appreciate that wont satisfy the immediate need to know but it may be the best way to manage the problem especially with such a low failure rate.

Comment: yeah this is probably the best idea, I'll just tighten things up a bit and try and set it up for a better error message and see if it happens again. Doesn't really affect much, they'd just have to refresh the page I'd guess.

Answer (score 1):

> It's only happened once and that
>   method has been called thousands of
>   times since the site went live.

After reading this, I can conclude that, its possible that .NET may have exhausted its memory and it could not create any more Dictionary key, it may not really be anywhere your fault. But yes we did get these kind of errors when we tried to store too much information in session/application variables thus increasing memory footprint of the Web Application. But we got such errors when our numbers went really high, like storing 10,000 items in Dictionary or List etc.

The pattern is good, but you must also realize that we use database to store information in relational format, if we start using memory to store similar things, then we are ignoring powerful database. Database can cache values for you as well.

It might sound silly but we have our windows server restart in every 24 hours, at midnight when there is no traffic. That did help us in getting rid of such errors. We restart our servers regularly at a fix schedule in order to get all the cache/logs cleared.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the comparison could be causing the problem.
Is any of the criteria for comparison contain null value?  specifically, the string properties?

i.e. If firstname or lastname or emailId is null and if it is used in comparison, things could fail when used inside the dictionary for comparison.

EDIT: How is Supervisor and StaffMember and AdminStaff class related?
In the code, you are casting both the instances to StaffMember. My guess is that it could be a problem if the Supervisor and StaffMember class are **not** related.

EDIT2: What is the scrope of the dictionary instance? Is it shared at application level/session level? Is it possible that multiple threads could try to read/write from it?

Comment: I would have thought the CompareTo method would have shown up in the stack trace though? Code is added to main post

I see your point, I'll add checking for nulls on lastnames, though they shouldnt be null, they are set in the constructor and returned from the sql database where they are set as 'NOT NULL' values

Comment: Supervisor and AdminOfficer are both types of StaffMember.

Inheritance tree is:
Staff Member
Supervisor
AdminOfficer

a Staff Member can either be a plain old StaffMember, a Supervisor or an AdminOfficer. A supervisor has a list of StaffMembers under their supervision in addition to the normal properties. They are separated like that mainly for validation purposes, when you login your username is associated with a StaffMember - if its an Supervisor you can do certain things StaffMembers cant, and you can do even more if you are an AdminOfficer

Comment: Is that an issue of string properties being null? Did you add the check for null? Is the exception occurring after that?

Comment: Thanks for your input shahkalpesh, I've added the check, it's a no-repro bug though (only got 1 email today, method has been called thousands of times). I dont believe that the firstNames can be null though - they're pulled straight from the database and the database dissalows null values on first names.

Answer (score 0):

Another way I have seen this exception, unrelated to threading, is when serializing a Dictionary. In this case, it was empty, but I still got the NullReferenceException in the Insert() method on the deserialized instance.

The simple change in my case was just to create a new instance after deserialization. I'm not sure whether the serialization just breaks the Dictionary, or if it is the types that the Dictionary is defined for.

In my case the types were not serializable without serialization surrogates (and I had provided these), but maybe something in the Dictionary had a problem here. Again though, the Dictionary was empty and this still happened.