# Static member variable throws null reference exception

Tags: c#

I have a class that maintains a static `Dictionary` to contain a map between string and another Object (`CloudFileClient` in my case). I haven't used static constructor but rather have initialized the variable while declaring.

Problem:

I am facing "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**" exception while adding a key to the dictionary. From the stack trace it looks like the Dictionary itself maybe null.

Sample code:

```
public class Demo
{
    // Initalizing the dictionary here.
    private static Dictionary<string, CloudFileClient> CloudFileClientReferences = new Dictionary<string, CloudFileClient>();
    ...

    public static Func<string, CloudFileClient> GetCloudFileClient { get; set; } = (string accountName) =>
    {
        if (!CloudFileClientReferences.ContainsKey(accountName))
        {
            CloudFileClientReferences[accountName] = CreateCloudFileClient(); // Problem statement.
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine but occassionaly the app is logging the following error at the "Problem statement" line.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior) \r\n at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2.set_Item(TKey key, TValue value)

What could be the issue here? I have hosted this code within Azure serverless function. I don't think `ConcurrentDictionary` would help here as the error would say so. Can a null key cause this? Or should I use static constructor instead?

Comment: _"...I don't think ConcurrentDictionary would help here..."_ Would have been easy to try out, wouldn't it?

Comment: Sounds like a multithreading problem that has provoked an error within the `Dictionary` implementation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Fundamentally, even if you *didn't* have this problem, you're using the not-thread-safe `Dictionary<,>` class in a mutable way potentially across multiple thread. Why would you expect the error to tell you that `ConcurrentDictionary` would solve the issue?

Comment: @UweKeim yes, I am going forward with that change. It will take some time to deploy and check. As I said it's happening randomly and I am not able to reproduce it in local system. Would be good to know, why the reference seems to be null even there is a clear initialization.

Comment: @JonSkeet it doesn't as I said. I would except errors like "Operations that change non-concurrent collections must have exclusive access. A concurrent update was performed on this collection and corrupted its state." to know that multi-threaded access is the cause here.

Comment: Could this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320621/throw-a-nullreferenceexception-while-calling-the-set-item-method-of-a-dictionary

Comment: @GautamKumarSamal: I was asking *why you would expect* it to say that. Do you have any evidence that it does that anywhere else? Typically non-thread-safe types like `Dictionary<,>` don't try to detect that you're using you're misusing them.

Comment: @GautamKumarSamal It's easy to show that it DOESN'T give you such warnings. Try this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nADYct (you may need to run it several times to see an error).

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand. I have faced error related to multi-threaded operations on a dictionary. Those always have a hint "concurrent" in the exception. Here it says that something is not an instance of object, essentially null I assume. Do you mean a multi-threaded access can trigger the said exception?

Comment: @derpirscher you are right. It's actually like "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2". I copied it from an editor that trated it as a markdown syntax. Sorry for that.

Comment: @GautamKumarSamal: I can't say I've ever personally seen an error message like that for `Dictionary<,>`. But fundamentally you're using a type "off-label" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0#thread-safety specifically says that what you're doing is not safe.

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess so. I'll try the concurrent dictionary and will update if it resolved things for me.