# Mysterious (Invalid?) NullReferenceException in C#

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

```
private readonly Dictionary<int, ManualResetEvent> _ack_events = new Dictionary<int, ManualResetEvent>();

private void ACKRecieved(int ackType)
{
    if (!_ack_events.ContainsKey(ackType))
    { 
        _ack_events.Add(ackType, new ManualResetEvent(true)); 
    }
    _ack_events[ackType].Set();
}
```

OK so here's the issue. Visual Studio throws an exception at the statement:

```
ack_events.Add(ackType, new ManualResetEvent(true));
```

How?

The type of `ackType` is an `int` so it can't be null and I don't see how `new ManualResetEvent(true)` could ever possibly evaluate to `null` either so... What gives? `_ack_events` is obviously not `null` either, as it gets initialized during construction.

All I can ask is... wha?

Comment: `ManualResetEvent` constructor could throw it.

Comment: Please show the full error message including the stack trace.

Comment: What's inside the constructor for ManualResetEvent?

Comment: @DavidG that's a .NET Framework class

Comment: Put a breakpoint right before that `if` statement, hit the breakpoint using a debug session, hover your mouse pointer over `_ack_events`, and tell me what you see.  Also, show us the entire stack trace.

Comment: Hello, I managed to reproduce your issue. This is the problem: [How did I get this NullReferenceException error here right after the constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320264/how-did-i-get-this-nullreferenceexception-error-here-right-after-the-constructor) - _"`Dictionary<>.Insert()` will throw a `NullReferenceException` internally if the dictionary instance is modified from another thread during the insert operation."_

Comment: Doing `ContainsKey` then some other operation is very inefficient instead use [`TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx), if that returns false then you do your Add. [Here is a example](https://gist.github.com/leftler/096b0ada4926bf9655d1)

Comment: @cubrr: Wow, that's... counter-intuitive.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's why there's [`ConcurrentDictionary<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for all your concurrent dictionary needs :o)

Comment: @RobertHarvey well, if you insist on using a non-threadsafe class from mutliple threads (without locks) that's the kind of things you risk ;)

Comment: @JoshuaPech - can you confirm that ACKRecieved() is called from multiple threads?

Comment: @HenkHolterman given the name of the function it's 99.999% sure, but if it's not the case I'll reopen the question.

Comment: @cubrr is absolutely right. Switching in a ConcurrentDictionary sorted the issue straight away.

I'd also like to point out that locks would not work in this case. I didn't even attempt locking because I know it would deadlock elsewhere in the code (not shown).